# how do we get info on azure app service failing with 502 error

Tags: azure, http

have been using azure for a while then tried deploying a new app service called sis. this runs great on local server then deploy to azure with no errors and get 502. nothing in the logs.

Comment: add proper logging, enable debug\diagnostic logging. without details of your app nothing more precise can be said